# Matplotlib - changing plot size within rectangular grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 4 subplots (created by using add_subplot) organised in a 2x2 rectangular grid. The two in the second row do not need to take up as much space and I wish to change it such that the top row takes up two thirds of the space and the bottom row takes up the remaining third.

I've found that you can arbitrarily place subplots by creating them with the axes function that takes a list of [top, left, width, height], but this would make the code a little messy and arbitrary.

Is there a "nice" way to do it? Or will I have to resort to individually placing each subplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subplot2grid](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/gridspec.html#basic-example-of-using-subplot2grid), where you specify a 3x3 grid but make subplots in the first row have `rowspan=2`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [AxisGrid toolkit](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axesgrid) will help. It seems to offer more control than subplot()